# Get OAuth2 token with grant_type=password

Tags: c#, authentication, web-services, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to configure the “universal” OAuth2 **client** authentication in C# by using `IServiceCollection.AddAccessTokenManagement -> ClientCredentialsTokenRequest` objects. I can create `grant_type=client_credentials` authentication without any issues, it works. Unfortunately, I don't know how to use `grant_type=password` in the same way. I have username, password, access token URL and ClientID which are required to get the valid token (in Postman it works). How can I implement something similar in C#?

```
private static void ConfigureOuathAuthentication(IServiceCollection services, OuathAuthenticationConfiguration ouathAuthenticationConfiguration)
{
    services.AddAccessTokenManagement(options =>
    {
        options.Client.Clients.Add("identityserver", new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
        {
            Address = ouathAuthenticationConfiguration.Address,
            ClientId = ouathAuthenticationConfiguration.ClientId,
            ClientSecret = ouathAuthenticationConfiguration.ClientSecret,
            Scope = ouathAuthenticationConfiguration.Scope, // optional
            GrantType = ouathAuthenticationConfiguration.GrantType
        });
    });

    services.AddClientAccessTokenHttpClient("client_ouath", configureClient: client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ouathAuthenticationConfiguration.Address);
    });
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this documentation: https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#resource-owner-password. Make sure that you pass all required parameters

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code snippet, I've added the `Resource Owner Password Credentials` flow, a.k.a `password` flow.

```
private static void ConfigureOuathAuthentication(IServiceCollection services, OuathAuthenticationConfiguration ouathAuthenticationConfiguration)
{
    services.AddAccessTokenManagement(options =>
    {
        options.Client.Clients.Add("identityserver", new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
        {
            Address = ouathAuthenticationConfiguration.Address,
            ClientId = ouathAuthenticationConfiguration.ClientId,
            ClientSecret = ouathAuthenticationConfiguration.ClientSecret,
            Scope = ouathAuthenticationConfiguration.Scope, // optional
            GrantType = ouathAuthenticationConfiguration.GrantType
        });
    });


    options.Client.Clients.Add("resource-owner", new UsernamePasswordTokenRequest
    {
        Address = "address-for-resource-owner-client",
        ClientId = "clientid-for-resource-owner-client",
        ClientSecret = "clientsecret-for-resource-owner-client",
        Scope = "scope-for-resource-owner-client",
        UserName = "your-username",
        Password = "your-password",
        GrantType = "password"
    });

    services.AddClientAccessTokenHttpClient("client_ouath", configureClient: client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ouathAuthenticationConfiguration.Address);
    });
}
```

If you have a valid identity provider behind it, and proper parameters are given, this should work.

Comment: in which library lives UsernamePasswordTokenRequest ?